# Move data from PostgreSQL to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with 50 tables which I need to export then import it in MySQL database. I need to maintain same table fields, data inside tables.

I am using pgAdmin III, tried using the Backup (Plain) feature but couldn't then import data and tables in mysql

I have also tried searching the web on how to do so but failed to locate any useful info so any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @Precious1tj I've tried the answer for this question but it didn't work :( I simply got many errors during the import operation in MySQL for the sql file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/
It has a Migration Wizard.

Comment: I've tried using MySQL migration toolkit but unfortunately the tool doesn't support importing from Postgresql! :(

Comment: Are you sure you had the latest version? On the page I linked to it mentions PostgreSQL as a supported DB.